# Medida en una tabla de hechos datawarehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo una duda en algunos conceptos en el tema de **data warehouse**, si alguien me lo pudiera aclarar estaría muy agradecido.

Para explicar mi duda, expondré el siguiente ejemplo. Se tiene el siguiente esquema **dimensional:**

[image: Modelado Dimensional de ejemplo]

Tomando en cuenta que existen medidas de tipo **Aditivas, Semi-Aditivas** y **No-Aditivas**.

De que forma se insertar los datos del promedio en la **tabla de hechos** siendo que un promedio es una medida de grano mas grueso? (Distinta granularidad).

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El promedio no se puede agregar en una tabla de hechos.

El promedio no es una medida que se pueda sumarizar, ni calcular en base a promedios. Es una medida que solo sirve sobre el universo a tomar en cuenta. Por lo tanto, esa medida se debe siempre calcular al momento de necesitarla.

Si tuvieras una tabla que dijera:

```
dia cantidad preciototal promedio
1   100      500         5
2   1000     1999        1.9
```

Fijate que si quisieramos calcular el promedio total, no alcanza con hacer la suma de los promedios, si no que tenemos que sumar las cantidad y los precios de vuelta:

```
// Promedio del promedio
(5 + 1.9) / 2 = 3.45

//Promedio de las sumas como corresponde
2499 / 1100 = 2.27
```

Por lo tanto, salvo que sea como referencia puntual, no sirve tener un promedio en cualquier nivel de hechos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de contestar, mi duda surgió a causa de que siempre que miro ejemplos de estos esquemas, aparecen totales y cosas por el estilo y no me hacen mucho sentido.